# Vuejs + gsap.to return object instead of number

Tags: vue.js, gsap

i'm trying to use tween to move object smoothly.
without gsap it works correctly

```
this.mesh.position.x = this.rot[1]
```

but when i add a tween it returns an object

```
this.mesh.position.x = TweenMax.to(this.data, 1, { movex:this.rot[1]})
```

**can you tell me how to use tween.to correctly?**

Comment: resolved, i need use this instead of this.data

Comment: Feel free to right an answer and accept it.